But why is the curl of a vector field a cross product?
I'm a first year undergrad student who is learning vector calculus. I've reached out to my professor at university, read math textbooks and browsed several online resources, but one thing has been bothering me about this topic. I have a fairly intuitive understanding of why divergence is the dot product of the del operator and a vector field thanks to the khan academy series on vector calculus. What I don't fully understand is why the notion of curl is associated with the cross product. I have a rough understanding of this topic, which I'll try to explain here. But I can't seem to apply this intuition to more general vector fields.
Consider the curl of the 3D vector field $\vec{F}(x,y,z)$. $curl\;\vec{F}(x,y,z)$ is a vector $\vec{C}(x,y,z)$ whose magnitude represents the extent to which the field is rotating counter clockwise at the point $(x,y,z)$. The direction of this vector represents the axis of rotation at that point. In other words, if you were to put a ball at that point, about what vector would it rotate?
If we narrow our perspective to the 2D case, it can be seen that when there is counter clockwise rotation at some point $(x,y)$, $\frac{\partial P}{\partial y} < 0$ and $\frac{\partial Q}{\partial x} > 0$ where $P(x,y)$ is the x-component of the vector field at $(x,y)$ while $Q(x,y)$ is the y-component of the vector field at $(x,y)$. This diagram from a khan academy video shows this idea:

Hence, an expression that reasonably captures the extent of counterclockwise rotation would be $\frac{\partial Q}{\partial x} - \frac{\partial P}{\partial y}$.
Now, consider the following vector field:
$\vec{F_1} = P(x,y)\hat{i} + Q(x,y)\hat{j}$. The curl must point in the $\hat{k}$ direction to have the appropriate axis of rotation. Further, it must have the magnitude $\frac{\partial Q}{\partial x} - \frac{\partial P}{\partial y}$. Hence, we can define the curl of $\vec{F_1}$ to be $\left(\frac{\partial Q}{\partial x} - \frac{\partial P}{\partial y}\right)\hat{k}$.
Consider, next, $\vec{F_2} = P(x,z)\hat{i} + R(x,z)\hat{k}$. Imagine viewing the vector field from the negative y-axis (as this would make x-axis point to the right and the z-axis point up).
Now, the appropriate expression for the "extent of counter clockwise rotation" would be: $\frac{\partial R}{\partial x} - \frac{\partial P}{\partial z}$. This time, the curl must point in the $-\hat{j}$ direction (since that's where we are viewing the vector field from) and we can define curl of $\vec{F_2}$ to be $-\left(\frac{\partial R}{\partial x} - \frac{\partial P}{\partial z}\right)\hat{j}$
Finally, consider $\vec{F_3} = Q(y,z)\hat{j} + R(y,z)\hat{k}$. Viewing from the +x axis, the extent of counter clockwise rotation is: $\frac{\partial R}{\partial y} - \frac{\partial Q}{\partial z}$. Hence, curl of $\vec{F_3}$ is: $\left(\frac{\partial R}{\partial y} - \frac{\partial Q}{\partial z}\right)\hat{i}$.
These are of course, special cases of the cross product formula. My question is, how can I build up this argument for any arbitrary vector field $\vec{F} = P(x,y,z)\hat{i} + Q(x,y,z)\hat{j} + R(x,y,z)\hat{k}$? My gut feel is that it would involve decomposing this arbitrary vector field into the special vector fields that have a zero in one of their components. A problem, however, is that in the special fields that I considered, the remaining two components don't depend on the third component. For example, $\vec{F_1} = P(x,y)\hat{i} + Q(x,y)\hat{j}$, and not $P(x,y,z)\hat{i} + Q(x,y,z)\hat{j}$. So, it's impossible to decompose $\vec{F}$ to $\vec{F_1}, \vec{F_2}, \vec{F_3}$
Is there a way to build up my argument to any arbitrary vector field? If there's not, I don't understand how the cross product of the del operator and the vector field magically produces a vector that points in the axis of rotation. No book I've read seems to address this problem, which, I think, is pretty essential when defining curl. They simply define the formula for curl and give the associated intuition for curl. They don't show how the formula arises from the intuition.

I think your confusion starts from the fact that you use $P, Q, R$ to mean different things. Is $P(x,y)$ same as $P(x,z)$?

@Andrei I don't understand how that's significant. I suppose I should have named the functions differently, $P_1(x,y)$, $P_2(x,z)$ and so on. I intended $P(x,y)$ and $P(x,z)$ to be different functions (and probably should have the named them differently for 100% accuracy)

Euler's rotation theorem says that rotation around multiple fixed axes are the same as one rotation about a single fixed axis. He shows it with spherical trigonometry.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_rotation_theorem

Define $$\mathop{\mathrm{curl}}_u\vec F(x,y,z):=[D_a(\vec F(x,y,z)\cdot b) - D_b(\vec F(x,y,z)\cdot a)]$$ for any unit vector $u$ and orthonormal $a,b$ such that $a\times b = u$ and where $D_a$ is the $a$-directional derivative. By your argument above, this is exactly how much $\vec F$ rotates about $(x,y,z)$ solely within the plane parallel to $u^\perp$ passing through that point. (1) Show that this is well defined, i.e. that any choice of $a,b$ for fixed $u$ gives the same thing. (2) Extend this definition to non-unit $u$ simply by multiplying by $|u|$ and requiring $a\times b = u/|u|$.

(3) Show that $\mathop{\mathrm{curl}}_u\vec F$ is linear in $u$. (4) Finally, it follows that there is a vector, $\mathop{\mathrm{curl}}\vec F$, such that $$(\mathop{\mathrm{curl}}\vec F)\cdot u = \mathop{\mathrm{curl}}_u\vec F$$ for all $u$.

The great thing about @NicholasTodoroff's approach is $a\times b$ can be defined as the vector solving $c\cdot u=[a b u]$ for all $u$, so while the advised calculation gives a proof of the formula for curl, just imagining doing it gives an intuition without our needing to make the effort. The Levi-Civita symbol's bound to crop up.

@NicholasTodoroff Unfortunately, I'm just a freshman studying Electrical Engineering and couldn't quite catch your reasoning. Would it be possible for you to elaborate your argument in more detail in an answer (Note: I'm familiar with some linear algebra)?

@Aryaan I didn't write an answer because I don't know how to follow through with the argument (in particular I was stuck trying to accomplish step 1 in a nice way). But I can explain some more. You agree that $x,y,z$ are completely arbitrary, right? In particular, we can replace $\hat i,\hat j,\hat k$ with any right-handed ($\hat i\times\hat j=\hat k$) orthonormal basis $a,b,u$. Partial derivatives are just directional derivatives e.g. $\partial/\partial x=D_{\hat i}$, so we use $D_a, D_b$ in place of $\partial/\partial x,\partial/\partial y$.

Components $\vec F=P\hat i+P\hat j$ are just dot products e.g. $P=\vec F\cdot\hat i$, so we use $\vec F\cdot a,\vec F\cdot b$ in place of $P,Q$. So what I'm saying is, let's consider the 2D scalar curl $\mathop{\mathrm{curl}}_u\vec F$ of $\vec F$ constrained to a plane with normal $u$. We need to show that it doesn't matter which $a,b$ you use to define this. Then, we want to show that this is a linear function of $u$ since every linear $\mathbb R^3 \to \mathbb R$ is of the form $w \mapsto v\cdot w$ for some unique $v$.

We then define this unique $v$ to be the total curl of $\vec F$. In other words, we have defined the curl so that $\mathop{\mathrm{curl}}\vec F(x,y,z)$ is the unique vector such that $(\mathop{\mathrm{curl}}\vec F(x,y,z))\cdot u$ is the 2D curl of $\vec F$ about the point $(x,y,z)$ in the plane orthogonal to $u$ passing through the point $(x,y,z)$.

I'd like to start this answer with a certain motivation for the curl which will more clearly specify what exactly it is that we expect the curl to do for us so that we have a straightforward path to it's mathematical expression.
We start by considering line integrals of a vector field $F$ around oriented closed curves,
$$\oint_C F \cdot dr$$
Which is also called the circulation of $F$ around $C$.
If we have two curves $C_1$, $C_2$ which partially overlap and have the opposite orientation along this overlap, for example these two,
 
And we sum the circulation of $F$ around $C_1$ with the circulation of $F$ around $C_2$,
$$\oint_{C_1} F \cdot dr + \oint_{C_2} F \cdot dr$$
Then it is fairly clear that the portion of the first circulation corresponding to the line integral of $F$ along the overlap will cancel with the portion of the second circulation corresponding to the line integral of $F$ along the overlap, as these two portions differ only by a minus sign corresponding to the opposite orientations of $C_1$ and $C_2$.
 
This leaves us with the circulation of $F$ around $C_3$, where $C_3$ is $C_1$ without the overlap adjoined to $C_2$ without the overlap.
$$= \oint_{C_3} F \cdot dr$$
This gives us an idea, given a surface $S$, whose boundary is the closed curve $C$, such as this one,

We can find the circulation of $F$ around $C$ by breaking up $S$ into small pieces and summing up the circulations of $F$ around these small pieces. All of the overlaps inside the surface will cancel each other out just as above, leaving us with only the circulation of $F$ around the boundary of the surface, which is $C$.
One way to approximate a surface is using parallelograms, for example here is the above surface approximated using 400 parallelograms,

If we have a parameterization of the surface $\Psi(u, v) = x(u, v) \hat i + y(u, v) \hat j + z(u, v) \hat k$ which maps surface coordinates $u, v$ to their corresponding positions in space, then a small square in parameter space of side lengths $\Delta u$, $\Delta v$ whose bottom left corner is at coordinates $u, v$ will approximately be mapped to the parallelogram formed by the vectors $\Delta u \frac{\partial \Psi}{\partial u}(u, v), \Delta v \frac{\partial \Psi}{\partial v}(u, v)$ and based at position $\Psi(u, v)$. The sum of the circulations of $F$ around all of these parallelograms is an approximation for the circulation of $F$ around $C$, you can imagine that this approximation approaches the exact value in the limit as the parallelograms become infinitesimally small.
We are then looking for some operation which will compute for us the circulation of $F$ around a parallelogram formed by the vectors $p, q$ and based at position $r$. Informally speaking, as we ultimately intend to use this on infinitesimal parallelograms, it will suffice to approximate $F$ to first order using the Jacobian,
$$F(r + h) \approx F(r) + J(r)h$$
$$J = \begin{bmatrix}
\frac{\partial F_x}{\partial x} & \frac{\partial F_x}{\partial y} & \frac{\partial F_x}{\partial z}\\
\frac{\partial F_y}{\partial x} & \frac{\partial F_y}{\partial y} & \frac{\partial F_y}{\partial z}\\
\frac{\partial F_z}{\partial x} & \frac{\partial F_z}{\partial y} & \frac{\partial F_z}{\partial z}
\end{bmatrix}$$
To keep things tidy I will define $F_0 = F(r)$ and no longer show the argument of the Jacobian, it is always $r$.
We can parameterize a path around this parallelogram as follows,
$$\gamma_1(\lambda) = r + \lambda p$$
$$\gamma_2(\lambda) = r + p + \lambda q$$
$$\gamma_3(\lambda) = r + p + q - \lambda p$$
$$\gamma_4(\lambda) = r + q - \lambda q$$
$$\gamma_1(0) = r$$
$$\gamma_1(1) = \gamma_2(0) = r + p$$
$$\gamma_2(1) = \gamma_3(0) = r + p + q$$
$$\gamma_3(1) = \gamma_4(0) = r + q$$
$$\gamma_4(1) = r$$
The circulation of $F$ around the parallelogram is then given by,
$$\int^1_0 F(\gamma_1) \cdot \frac{d \gamma_1}{d \lambda} d\lambda + \int^1_0 F(\gamma_2) \cdot \frac{d \gamma_2}{d \lambda} d\lambda + \int^1_0 F(\gamma_3) \cdot \frac{d \gamma_3}{d \lambda} d\lambda + \int^1_0 F(\gamma_4) \cdot \frac{d \gamma_4}{d \lambda} d\lambda$$
$$\frac{d \gamma_1}{d \lambda} = p$$
$$\frac{d \gamma_2}{d \lambda} = q$$
$$\frac{d \gamma_3}{d \lambda} = -p$$
$$\frac{d \gamma_4}{d \lambda} = -q$$
$$F(\gamma_1) \approx F_0 + \lambda Jp$$
$$F(\gamma_2) \approx F_0 + Jp + \lambda Jq$$
$$F(\gamma_3) \approx F_0 + Jp + Jq - \lambda Jq$$
$$F(\gamma_4) \approx F_0 + Jq - \lambda Jq$$
Plugging these into our integrals,
$$= \int^1_0 (F_0 + \lambda Jp) \cdot p d\lambda$$
$$+ \int^1_0 (F_0 + Jp + \lambda Jq) \cdot q d\lambda$$
$$+ \int^1_0 (F_0 + Jp + Jq - \lambda Jq) \cdot -p d\lambda$$
$$+ \int^1_0 (F_0 + Jq - \lambda Jq) \cdot -q d\lambda$$
$$= F_0 \cdot p + \frac{1}{2}(J p) \cdot p$$
$$+ F_0 \cdot q + (J p) \cdot q + \frac{1}{2}(J q) \cdot q$$
$$- F_0 \cdot p - (J p) \cdot p - (J q) \cdot p + \frac{1}{2}(J p) \cdot p$$
$$- F_0 \cdot q - (J q) \cdot q + \frac{1}{2}(J q) \cdot q$$
All terms except 2 cancel, which we convert to matrix notation,
$$= (J p) \cdot q - (J q) \cdot p$$
$$= q^T J p - q^T J^T p$$
$$= q^T (J - J^T) p$$
This formula actually works in n dimensions but in 3 dimensions we can use the cross product to express it purely in terms of vectors.
As the cross product is linear in it's arguments,
$$w \times (av_1 + bv_2) = a w \times v_1 + b v \times v_2$$
It follows that for each vector $w$ there exists a matrix such that,
$$[w]_{\times} v = w \times v$$
$[w]_{\times}$ is called the cross product matrix of $w$ and is given by,
$$[w]_{\times} = \begin{bmatrix}
0 & -w_z & w_y\\
w_z & 0 & -w_x\\
-w_y & w_x & 0
\end{bmatrix}$$
We can note that the cross product matrix is skew-symmetric, $[w]_{\times}^T = -[w]_{\times}$. It's also fairly clear that each 3x3 skew-symmetric matrix corresponds to a vector. We notice that $J - J^T$ from our above results is a skew-symmetric matrix, and therefor there must exist some vector $w$ which it is the cross product matrix of, using this to rewrite our result,
$$= q^T [w]_{\times} p$$
Converting back to vector notation and using the scalar triple product identity,
$$= q \cdot (w \times p)$$
$$= w \cdot (p \times q)$$
We see that rather than specifying our parallelogram using two vectors $p, q$ we can instead specify it using a single vector $n = p \times q$ whose magnitude is the area of parallelogram and whose direction is normal to it, the right hand rule tells us which way to compute the circulation of $F$ around the parallelogram.
Examining $J - J^T$,
$$J - J^T = \begin{bmatrix}
0 & \frac{\partial F_x}{\partial y} - \frac{\partial F_y}{\partial x} & \frac{\partial F_x}{\partial z} - \frac{\partial F_z}{\partial x}\\
\frac{\partial F_y}{\partial x} - \frac{\partial F_x}{\partial y} & 0 & \frac{\partial F_y}{\partial z} - \frac{\partial F_z}{\partial y}\\
\frac{\partial F_z}{\partial x} - \frac{\partial F_x}{\partial z} & \frac{\partial F_z}{\partial y} - \frac{\partial F_y}{\partial z} & 0
\end{bmatrix}$$
We can see that the vector $w$ is given by,
$$w = \left( \frac{\partial F_z}{\partial y} - \frac{\partial F_y}{\partial z} \right) \hat i + \left( \frac{\partial F_x}{\partial z} - \frac{\partial F_z}{\partial x} \right) \hat j + \left( \frac{\partial F_y}{\partial x} - \frac{\partial F_x}{\partial y} \right) \hat k$$
Which we define to be the curl of $F$, $\nabla \times F$.
$n \cdot \nabla \times F$ tells us the first order approximation of the circulation of $F$ around a parallelogram whose area is $|n|$ and whose normal is given by $\hat n$.
Our formula for the circulation of $F$ around $C$ is then,
$$\oint_C F \cdot dr = \iint_U \nabla \times F \cdot \left( \frac{\partial \Psi}{\partial u} \times \frac{\partial \Psi}{\partial v} \right) dudv$$
Where $U$ is the the region of $\mathbb{R}^2$ corresponding to coordinates on the surface. Written more abstractly,
$$= \iint_S \nabla \times F \cdot dS$$
Where $dS = \left( \frac{\partial \Psi}{\partial u} \times \frac{\partial \Psi}{\partial v} \right) dudv$. Which is Stokes' theorem.
I hope this answer has been able to shed some light on where the curl comes from and why it has the specific form which it does.

I think the most intuitive understanding of divergence and curl comes from Gauss' theorem and Stokes' theorem (which are both special cases of the generalized Stokes' theorem):
$$
\iiint_V(\nabla\cdot\boldsymbol F)\,\mathrm dV={\vcenter{
   \huge\unicode{x222F}\,
  }}_{\partial V}\boldsymbol F\cdot\mathrm d\boldsymbol S,\\
\iint_S(\nabla\times\boldsymbol F)\cdot\mathrm d\boldsymbol S=\oint_{\partial S}\boldsymbol F\cdot\mathrm d\boldsymbol l.
$$
For Gauss' theorem, the right-hand side can be intutively thought of as the "outgoing flux" through the surface $\partial V$, because the dot product $\boldsymbol F\cdot\mathrm d\boldsymbol S$ gives the length of $\boldsymbol F$ in the direction of the normal vector. Here's a picture that I found on physicsanduniverse.com that illustrates the idea quite clearly:

We can then take $V$ infinitesimally small such that the left-hand side simply becomes $\nabla\cdot\boldsymbol F$. This is why the divergence measures the "flux" at a given point.
For Stokes' theorem, the right-hand side can be thought of as how much the field $\boldsymbol F$ rotates, because $\partial S$ is a closed curve, and if the integral is positive, then it means that the field is roughly rotating in the counterclockwise direction (by the usual sign convention). If the integral is negative, then it rotates in the clockwise direction. Now we can choose $S$ infinitesimally small such that the left-hand side becomes $\nabla\times\boldsymbol F$, which is the curl of the vector field.
More generally, the generalized Stokes theorem states that the integral of a differential form ${\displaystyle \omega }$ over the boundary ${\displaystyle \partial \Omega }$ of some orientable manifold $Ω$ is equal to the integral of its exterior derivative $\mathrm d\omega$ over $\Omega$:
$$
\int_{\partial \Omega}\omega =\int_{\Omega}\mathrm d\omega.
$$
Divergence and curl are examples of the exterior derivative. See this Wikipedia page https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exterior_derivative#Gradient and Spivak's book "Calculus on Manifolds" for more information about exterior derivatives and the generalized Stokes' theorem. (I would say it is a good book to introduce yourself to some elementary differential geometry.)
